# members initializing using "this"

Tags: java

here is my problem

```
class A{
  private B b = new B(this); // line 2

  A(){}
}
```

This is just an ex. code and works fine. But i have a doubt about `this` is used to current reference (instance of A). Class initializing happens before to get a class instance. So how can we put `this` in line 2. i asked does instantiation happen before initializing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You bring up an interesting point.  Here is a contrived instructional example that demonstrates a run time problem that can happen when using your example.

```
class A {
    private boolean isInitialized = false;
    private final B b             = new B(this);
    public A() {
        initialize();
    }
    private void initialize() {
        isInitialized = true;
    }
    public boolean isInitialize() {
        return isInitialized;
    }
    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }
}

class B {
    private boolean isInitialized = false;
    final private A a;
    public B(final A a) {
        this.a = a;
        initialize();
        System.out.println("inB:          a.isInitialize()=" + a.isInitialize());
    }
    private void initialize() {
        isInitialized = true;
    }
    public boolean isInitialize() {
        return isInitialized;
    }
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final A a = new A();
    System.out.println("inMain:       a.isInitialize()=" + a.isInitialize());
    System.out.println("inMain:a.getB().isInitialize()=" + a.getB().isInitialize());
}
```

Output:

```
inB:          a.isInitialize()=false
inMain:       a.isInitialize()=true
inMain:a.getB().isInitialize()=true
```

Using the passed reference to class A within class B runs the real risk of using an object that is not fully initialized.

Be careful.

Answer (score 1):

This is not class initialization (try to debug `new ClassA()` step by step), it is actually instance initialization.

There can be some problems if the constructor (from `ClassB`) calls some functions from `ClassA`, which access some fields in `ClassA` that are not initialized.

**Edit**: this is done before the constructor is called.

Comment: what do you mean by instance initialization and class initialization ?

Answer (score 0):

`this` will show its existence when you create an object of class A. Instance variable are assigned after object creation and static variable are initialize as soon as class loads and also before creations of any object. 
you cannot use above initialization in static block

```
static {
    private B b = new B(this); // compiler error. you cannot use 'this' in static context.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is used correctly. The constructor doesn't need to be called at all.

Answer (score 0):

No need for changes, everything is fine. `this` is a valid reference to A.